# IE6 Two Div's inside a wrapper div, one div refuses to change width when the contents change

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I have two divs wrapped by another div. One of the div's is a header, the other will contain an image. I want the content div to wrap the with the correct aspect ratio of the image.

The wrapper div has minimum widths and heights specified. The image can have an arbitrary width specified. The height of the content div should adjust depending on the image height.

It works fine in FF, but in IE6 the header width does not change when the wrapper div changes to accommodate the specified image width.

Here's a fiddle. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sharpbarb/Gesnz/)

Here's a picture of the problem: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypjuf.png)

Comment: Can you please take a screenshot of the page in ie6 put it up here. Also, is there a REALLY big reason why you are trying to accommodate ie6?

Comment: Yup, there's a really big reason for accomodating ie6. I'm working on my department's website and, unfortunately, we're on ie6 company wide. I can't grab a screen shot at the moment. Basically, the container width is 100px and the header width is 100% and the image width is 150... The container grows to accomodate the larger image width, but the header doesn't; it just ends at 100px. (The blue header does span the container)

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but i fixed it so the text appears ontop properly in the fiddle. I dont have IE 6 at home to try it out. http://jsfiddle.net/Gesnz/6/ The line-height:0; on the wrapper was causing some major issues.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that didn't exactly work. [Image :)](http://i.imgur.com/pmiQp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE6, the header element is going to take up the amount of space defined by it's container element. In this case #testWrapper, which is set to 100px. IE6 won't play very nicely with absolutely positioned elements or floats with widths set to auto. I'd suggest defining the width that you want in #testWrapper and setting the img to 100%, if possible.

```
    #testWrapper{
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 0; 
        left: 0; 
        margin: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        width:150px; 
    }

    #testHeader {
        background: blue;
        height: 10px;
    }

    #testContent {
        background: black;
    }

    #testimage {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
```